# Python TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have the beer reviews examples from the rate beers data that I have run a hundred times. However after a recent upgrade to Py3.6 and the newest Numpy I am getting a error: T**ypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'.** I have not seen before nor really can figure out how to debug. My code below and full error below that.

```
def get_beer_reviews(beer, common_users):
    mask = (df.review_profilename.isin(common_users)) &
    (df.beer_name==beer)
    reviews = df[mask].sort_values('review_profilename')
    reviews = reviews[reviews.review_profilename.duplicated()==False]
    return reviews
beer_1_reviews = get_beer_reviews(beer_1, common_reviewers)
beer_2_reviews = get_beer_reviews(beer_2, common_reviewers)

cols = ['beer_name', 'review_profilename', 'review_overall', 
'review_aroma', 'review_palate', 'review_taste']
beer_2_reviews[cols].head()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8b20c3601bd3> in <module>()
      4     reviews = reviews[reviews.review_profilename.duplicated()==False]
      5     return reviews
----> 6 beer_1_reviews = get_beer_reviews(beer_1, common_reviewers)
      7 beer_2_reviews = get_beer_reviews(beer_2, common_reviewers)
      8 

<ipython-input-15-8b20c3601bd3> in get_beer_reviews(beer, common_users)
      1 def get_beer_reviews(beer, common_users):
----> 2     mask = (df.review_profilename.isin(common_users)) & (df.beer_name==beer)
      3     reviews = df[mask].sort_values('review_profilename')
      4     reviews = reviews[reviews.review_profilename.duplicated()==False]
      5     return reviews

/Users/mpgartland/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in isin(self, values)
   2553 
   2554         """
-> 2555         result = algorithms.isin(_values_from_object(self), values)
   2556         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   2557 

/Users/mpgartland/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in isin(comps, values)
    419             comps = comps.astype(object)
    420 
--> 421     return f(comps, values)
    422 
    423 

/Users/mpgartland/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in <lambda>(x, y)
    399     f = lambda x, y: htable.ismember_object(x, values)
    400     if (_np_version_under1p8 and compat.PY3) or len(comps) > 1000000:
--> 401         f = lambda x, y: np.in1d(x, y)
    402     elif is_integer_dtype(comps):
    403         try:

/Users/mpgartland/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in in1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique, invert)
    398     # Otherwise use sorting
    399     if not assume_unique:
--> 400         ar1, rev_idx = np.unique(ar1, return_inverse=True)
    401         ar2 = np.unique(ar2)
    402 

/Users/mpgartland/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    209 
    210     if optional_indices:
--> 211         perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort' if return_index else 'quicksort')
    212         aux = ar[perm]
    213     else:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: The exception indicates that you would have had a bug before, in Python 2, where numbers are always sorted before strings (not compared by value).

Comment: yes this was originally done in 2.7 and I have been moving all my stuff to 3.6 and been able to fix most inconsistencies. Suggestions on code modification? thx.

Comment: So is your content mixing floats and strings? The traceback suggests `df.review_profilename.isin(common_users)` is the trigger here, so `df.review_profilename` or `common_users` are the suspects.